# Unconfirmed transaction sitting in blockchain.info for 10 days

Tags: blockchain.info

I have this unconfirmed transaction:
https://blockchain.info/tx/b0d2e665a4c32deebac93ddd8e457bad6d3906834d908efecbf81a858ac92ae2

sitting in blockchain.info wallet for 10 days. When will the network drop it?

At the time of sending it, I did not change any fee and left it on blockchain.info wallet to calculate fee..

Answer (score 0):

> When will the network drop it?

Never. Why should network drop your transaction without an action from your side?

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/46162/38618 " transaction expired by timeout (by default 14 days after entering)."

Comment: this is not the "network drop it"