# Synchronize mempool between 3 nodes

Tags: mempool, bitcore

Three [bitcore](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcoin) nodes (version of bitcoind is quite old - 0.12.1) are deployed to the servers on different cloud platforms.

All instances have the same bitcoin.conf files (except of rpcallowip, rpcuser and rpcpassword):

```
server=1
whitelist=127.0.0.1

txindex=1
addressindex=1
timestampindex=1
spentindex=1

zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332

rpcthreads=8
rpcworkqueue=32
rpcservertimeout=60
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcuser=...
rpcpassword=...
uacomment=bitcore
```

The problem is all of them have considerably different mempools:

- first has **33689** txs in mempool
- second has **58219** txs
- third node has **39540** txs
- blockchain.info has **63598** txs

I understand, that mempool is node-specific and there is no "Single Bitcoin Network Mempool". However I need synchronization at least between these three nodes (though it would be better to be as close to blockchain.info as possible).

If there is transaction, that exists in blokchain.info's mempool, but doesn't exist in *all three* nodes' mempools - it is ok. But as soon as this transaction get to one of these three nodes, it should appear on others as soon as possible.

I've tried using `addnode` option to force nodes connect to each other, but it didn't helped.

May be I am missing something, or at least there is a way to find the reason of so big differences in mempool ?

---

Aim of consistent mempool.

We have mobile client and application server, all looking into these nodes (some kind of load balancing). User can be logged into one account on different devices. When server sees transaction in mempool, it should update user's status.

When mempools differ it is possible, that:

1. User will see different transactions on different devices, which may mess him
2. User will see transaction, and server will miss it. In such situation user expects, that status will be updated, but server wouldn't do it

So it would be very nice, to have (almost) equal mempools.

---

So far.

I've tried:

- `addnode` (to connect to specific nodes)
- `connect` (to connect **only** to specific nodes), to give it a try, thanks to @whatever

This options were described here, on [bitcoin.se](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41426/how-do-i-configure-bitcoin-core-to-connect-always-to-a-particular-node), and (alongside with other possible options for bitcoind) in [bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin). But there is still problem with big difference in mempool's size.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you told us what problem you're trying to solve by synchronizing the mempools.

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/dev7ba/mempoolcp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force mempool synchronization by running a script which connects to the RPC ports, fetches transactions from one node's mempool, and sends it to the other nodes. Note that because this uses RPC, it will be fairly slow and will still result in some mempool desynchronization. You will probably want to run this script periodically. Here is an example in python using `python-bitcoinrpc`.

Note: I have not tested this

```
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy, JSONRPCException

# rpc_user and rpc_password are set in the bitcoin.conf file
nodes = []
NODE1_URL = "10.10.10.1:8332"
NODE2_URL = "10.10.10.2:8332"
NODE3_URL = "10.10.10.3:8332"
nodes.append(AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@%s"%(rpc_user, rpc_password, NODE1_URL)))
nodes.append(AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@%s"%(rpc_user, rpc_password, NODE2_URL)))
nodes.append(AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@%s"%(rpc_user, rpc_password, NODE3_URL)))

for node in nodes:
    txs = node.getrawmempool()
    for tx in txs:
        rawtx = node.getrawtransaction(tx)
        for b_node in nodes:
            b_node.sendrawtransaction(rawtx)
```

What this does is it fetches a list of transaction ids in a node's mempool. Then it fetches each transaction and broadcasts them through the other nodes. It does this for each node. This, in theory, ensures that all of the nodes will have the same transactions in their mempool.

Comment: This is the approach i'm using to keep a fresh mempool between two nodes when I have to reboot one of them or send the whole mempool to a new one. But I've found that the transaction set it's not the same between them. One lacks some transaction from the other. The more times you execute this script (or equivalent) the more the two sets are the same. The reason? I think is because CPFP and dependant transactions: If the script sends a child Tx before it's parent, bitcoin node will reject it. The more you execute the script the more parents you have. And the mempool will eventually converge.

Comment: This script could be updated to take this into account. If I have time in the future, I'll try to post it here.

Comment: Also, I've realized that it could be that a transaction is not accepted by a node due to the first seen policy. This must be also taken into account: for example, a tx1 is relayed with low fees and node1 is up but node2 is down, tx1 is not replaceable by bip 125, but *anyways* another replacing tx2 is broadcasted to the network with more fees, this time node 1 and 2 are up. Node 1 rejects tx2, but Node 2 does not. If you try to send tx1 from node1 to node 2 with the script above it will be rejected by node2.

Comment: If anyone think this a corner-case and can't be seen see: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99717/transaction-being-ignored-by-miners-i-mean-ignored-not-not-mined-because-low

Comment: I finally made a cmd utility to resolve this: https://github.com/dev7ba/mempoolcp

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed 2 things:

1. If I started second node, when first had 1000 txs in mempool, then second node will have 1000 txs less (almost) constantly till mempool clearing. This means that all newly broadcasted txs hit all (three) mempools, but newer nodes cannot catch up with older nodes.
2. Periodically mempools decrease abruptly (from 70 thousands to 40 thousands for example). Nodes remove [expired](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43155/do-unconfirmed-transactions-expire-after-some-time/43165) transactions or reach their `maxmempool` size and clean mempool. After this event, amount of transactions is roughly the same on all three nodes (difference is less than 100 txs, comparable to several thousands in my case).

---

Old transactions seems not to be broadcasted by nodes. And it looks right, because if nodes will broadcast all their mempool transactions all the time, network will be bloated by unnecessary information. **So new node can catch up with old one only when all transaction, that existed before new node's start, will be deleted from mempools** (by either [way](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46152/how-do-transactions-leave-the-memory-pool/46162#46162)). However may be I am mistaken and there is a way to force new node fetch all transactions from mempool of older node.

(Almost) All new transactions will be in mempools of (almost) all running nodes. Mempools sooner or later will become roughly the same in size. The less time there is between the start of your node - the better (difference will be smaller).

So if you need to sync mempools, use `addnode=IP:PORT` option in your bitcoin.conf file (just to be sure that your nodes are talking to each other) and wait a little bit (approximately 72 hours) and mempools will be as close as possible to each other. However as far as I understood, there is always the possibility that some transactions will be missing in some mempools and there is no way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You could set 2 nodes to `connect` to 1 node and nothing else.

Comment: You might want to add some details to your answer to show the necessary modifications to `bitcoin.conf`

Comment: As far as I understand, `connect` says to connect _only_ to specified node.
Then 'master' node appears, and if it stops working, its 'slaves' becomes useless (they wouldn't get any updates and wouldn't be able to broadcast txs).

Comment: Of course, but it solves your requirement. You didn't mention HA was a requirement (in fact you have 3 servers, so you have HA, but you could have 6 or use failover or other approaches to address that). `connect` is the parameter to connect to other nodes, that's the only modification required (to Max's point).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the answer by @Andrew above but instead of using the script use mempoolcp command line utility. https://github.com/dev7ba/mempoolcp

Mempoolpc takes into account the dependencies between transactions and the fact that you can't send a child tx before a parent tx, or a parent tx before a grandparent tx... because otherwise, the sent transactions could be denied by the receiving node. The script above does not have this into consideration.