# Transaction being ignored by miners, I mean Ignored, Not "not mined because low fees"

Tags: mining-pools, mempool

I'm working on a project to visualize the mempool and (also) check if a transaction is being ignored by miners.

I have my own mining queue, to compare "my first block" with the block that has been mined. Comparing that block with mine I can take many statistics about weather a miner is choosing the best txs and/or is behaving correctly.

Project is currently in development and I have the backend more or less complete. Front-End is incomplete. So sorry if I can give you a link to it.

Today I've found that tx c3f92fe9ec20218a8c3d38b4852c9a88779d3128abdd43ac8c249207d8d3b530 has been ignored 86 times until now. And currently It's the first transaction that **should** be mined with 786 sat/VByte.

My bitcoin node shows that this transaction entered my mempool 20 hours ago. It's a short transaction with only 764 weight units, one input, one output, 0.24 bitcoins. Nothing special?

Also, my bitcoin node is using the tor network.

The transaction does not appear in known blockchain explorers so it seems that it has not been relayed properly. The transaction has bip125 enabled, so it could be that the person or entity broadcasting that transaction had increased many times the transaction fee.

So I'm wondering what is happening with this transaction. Anybody out there has any idea?

Maybe bitcoin nodes in tor network has poor conectivity with miners?

FYI: These are the blocks who has ignored the transaction up to date:

````
height: 654568,
totalTxNumMined: 2762,
postitionInQueue: 5
},
{
height: 654569,
totalTxNumMined: 2746,
postitionInQueue: 4
},
{
height: 654570,
totalTxNumMined: 2177,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654571,
totalTxNumMined: 3044,
postitionInQueue: 2
},
{
height: 654572,
totalTxNumMined: 2824,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654574,
totalTxNumMined: 0,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654575,
totalTxNumMined: 2706,
postitionInQueue: 3
},
{
height: 654576,
totalTxNumMined: 2515,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654578,
totalTxNumMined: 3141,
postitionInQueue: 3
},
{
height: 654579,
totalTxNumMined: 3040,
postitionInQueue: 6
},
{
height: 654580,
totalTxNumMined: 2501,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654581,
totalTxNumMined: 2399,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654582,
totalTxNumMined: 2889,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654583,
totalTxNumMined: 2098,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654584,
totalTxNumMined: 2973,
postitionInQueue: 5
},
{
height: 654585,
totalTxNumMined: 2135,
postitionInQueue: 4
},
{
height: 654586,
totalTxNumMined: 2451,
postitionInQueue: 6
},
{
height: 654587,
totalTxNumMined: 2312,
postitionInQueue: 8
},
{
height: 654588,
totalTxNumMined: 2614,
postitionInQueue: 5
},
{
height: 654589,
totalTxNumMined: 2946,
postitionInQueue: 2
},
{
height: 654590,
totalTxNumMined: 3170,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654591,
totalTxNumMined: 2624,
postitionInQueue: 7
},
{
height: 654592,
totalTxNumMined: 2638,
postitionInQueue: 4
},
{
height: 654593,
totalTxNumMined: 2988,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654594,
totalTxNumMined: 2781,
postitionInQueue: 11
},
{
height: 654595,
totalTxNumMined: 2486,
postitionInQueue: 3
},
{
height: 654596,
totalTxNumMined: 2423,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654597,
totalTxNumMined: 2526,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654598,
totalTxNumMined: 2973,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654599,
totalTxNumMined: 2866,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654600,
totalTxNumMined: 2910,
postitionInQueue: 10
},
{
height: 654601,
totalTxNumMined: 1814,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654602,
totalTxNumMined: 2642,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654603,
totalTxNumMined: 2572,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654604,
totalTxNumMined: 2068,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654605,
totalTxNumMined: 2300,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654606,
totalTxNumMined: 1911,
postitionInQueue: 3
},
{
height: 654607,
totalTxNumMined: 2503,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654608,
totalTxNumMined: 2060,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654609,
totalTxNumMined: 1666,
postitionInQueue: 5
},
{
height: 654610,
totalTxNumMined: 2241,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654611,
totalTxNumMined: 1947,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654612,
totalTxNumMined: 1496,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654613,
totalTxNumMined: 2140,
postitionInQueue: 4
},
{
height: 654614,
totalTxNumMined: 2460,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654615,
totalTxNumMined: 1338,
postitionInQueue: 2
},
{
height: 654616,
totalTxNumMined: 2320,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654617,
totalTxNumMined: 2394,
postitionInQueue: 2
},
{
height: 654618,
totalTxNumMined: 2630,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654619,
totalTxNumMined: 2858,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654620,
totalTxNumMined: 2097,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654621,
totalTxNumMined: 2856,
postitionInQueue: 5
},
{
height: 654622,
totalTxNumMined: 2379,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654623,
totalTxNumMined: 2585,
postitionInQueue: 5
},
{
height: 654624,
totalTxNumMined: 2434,
postitionInQueue: 2
},
{
height: 654625,
totalTxNumMined: 2032,
postitionInQueue: 6
},
{
height: 654626,
totalTxNumMined: 2667,
postitionInQueue: 4
},
{
height: 654627,
totalTxNumMined: 2521,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654628,
totalTxNumMined: 2662,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654629,
totalTxNumMined: 2313,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654630,
totalTxNumMined: 1995,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654631,
totalTxNumMined: 2330,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654632,
totalTxNumMined: 2588,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654633,
totalTxNumMined: 2775,
postitionInQueue: 3
},
{
height: 654634,
totalTxNumMined: 2604,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654635,
totalTxNumMined: 2135,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654636,
totalTxNumMined: 2540,
postitionInQueue: 2
},
{
height: 654637,
totalTxNumMined: 2244,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654638,
totalTxNumMined: 1231,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654639,
totalTxNumMined: 2367,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654640,
totalTxNumMined: 2370,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654641,
totalTxNumMined: 2935,
postitionInQueue: 4
},
{
height: 654642,
totalTxNumMined: 2453,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654643,
totalTxNumMined: 2414,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654644,
totalTxNumMined: 3102,
postitionInQueue: 6
},
{
height: 654645,
totalTxNumMined: 3211,
postitionInQueue: 5
},
{
height: 654646,
totalTxNumMined: 2561,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654648,
totalTxNumMined: 1931,
postitionInQueue: 10
},
{
height: 654649,
totalTxNumMined: 2578,
postitionInQueue: 2
},
{
height: 654650,
totalTxNumMined: 2588,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654651,
totalTxNumMined: 3038,
postitionInQueue: 7
},
{
height: 654652,
totalTxNumMined: 1305,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654653,
totalTxNumMined: 2260,
postitionInQueue: 3
},
{
height: 654654,
totalTxNumMined: 2627,
postitionInQueue: 1
},
{
height: 654655,
totalTxNumMined: 1980,
postitionInQueue: 2
},
{
height: 654656,
totalTxNumMined: 2645,
postitionInQueue: 0
},
{
height: 654658,
totalTxNumMined: 2861,
postitionInQueue: 5
}```
````

Comment: Is it possible that the transaction depending on unconfirmed inputs? It would help if you provided the full transaction, especially its input set.

Comment: No, the transaction was not dependant on any other, (my project even draw a graph of txs dependencies). but sadly I've had to delete mempool.dat of my mempool node since my algorithm was not performing fine under the big mempool of last days, the cpu was 100%, and my computer was stuck. Anyway I'll be monitoring the mempool next days. If I found any other Txs. I'll let you know. By the way I'll read your Master Thesis next days. ;-) Thanks.

Comment: I agree with Chytrik, my first bunch would also expect some other issue at play. I'll be curious to hear about it when you find another.

Comment: fa0dee70658fd00d6d205f673e79e3481cdba57100db576f2a7a308591a1c5e0 does not appear in https://mempool.observer/ nor https://blockstream.info or https://mempool.space Pays 64 sat/VByte which is now enough  to be mined. Has been ignored 14 times from block 655212 to 655227 by miners: huobi, bitdeer, 1thash&58coin, poolin, antpool, f2pool, btc.com and binance.

Comment: Depends on txs: b6bc98c8d29893f2a6e04fa3bd84f60958293739dbec0af8670c446247c3c923, 23dff917408de07b05762ceb3ebe90b07889e5da6ed74d8f4d607d3bae20705e, 414ba5ca29d582452d101a26c944b2a8ffa3e0c6407215ca0ef08c9d5dd3e0d8, f9d4f7cc3cae21da8ed864654db405dcbc90a43e811ebafa999aa83c1ec323c9, 0020bc825433a7f085afcd3288f6eb7868b806bb9efa6461ad1e7e1f2b733138 each one been confirmed 30000 blocks ago...

Comment: I cannot paste the hexadecimal representation here because it's too long. weight: 3116. Do you need more information?

Comment: I don't see the transaction on blockexplorers. I think it might be non-standard. Could you post the tx in a gist on github for example?

Comment: Great, thanks. The tx is invalid. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to the second transaction: It seems that it's a replacement for another transaction: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/3791f433180a6807695da26e1c0b7f7328a15cbe727ad4ce7c7acbc18b77c5a0
but it does not allows replacement by bip 125.

As I'm stopping my development node when needed, it seems that this transaction was not in my node before receiving the second one (fa0dee70658fd00d6d205f673e79e3481cdba57100db576f2a7a308591a1c5e0). So it was accepted. The other node I have (pi4) rejects that transaction because its online all the time, and had tx 3791f433180a6807695da26e1c0b7f7328a15cbe727ad4ce7c7acbc18b77c5a0 before.

In brief: Some people/program was sending a replacement for a transaction which does not allow it and my node took it as the original.

Thanks a lot @Murch

Comment: Right, the original transaction had set all its nSequence numbers to final, so it was not marked for replacement. Therefore the replacement got ignored per the first-seen-safe rule. To read more see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/49518/5406

Comment: For anyone wondering how to seach for transaction outputs in the mempool: blockchair.com has a beta API which allows some queries by value or address. https://blockchair.com/api/docs#link_400

Answer (score 1):

I've checked my node, and it has no evidence of transaction `c3f92fe9ec20218a8c3d38b4852c9a88779d3128abdd43ac8c249207d8d3b530`.

Additionally, I checked a couple of block explorer websites, and none of them show any result for this transaction.

So it seems that this transaction was either not relayed through the wider network, or it was dropped by network nodes for some reason (network fees have been very high, some mempools might be hitting their memory limits). Without additional information, it is not possible to know.

Generally, we wouldn't expect all miners to ignore a high-fee-rate transaction, so there must be some other issue at play.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into the second tx posted by the asker: fa0dee70658fd00d6d205f673e79e3481cdba57100db576f2a7a308591a1c5e0

It doesn't appear on any explorers. I noticed that all inputs were listed as being `vout: 0`, e.g. the input list states

```
{
  "addressIds": [
    "123h581GZtFAucMPpa3hFBCedEifaka5g9"
  ],
  "amount": 76559401,
  "txId": "f9d4f7cc3cae21da8ed864654db405dcbc90a43e811ebafa999aa83c1ec323c9",
  "coinbase": null,
  "voutIndex": 0
},
```

for one of the inputs.

However, the unspent was actually the sixth output (`vout: 5`) when it was created:

[image]

When I put the txhex into https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/push, it fails with `sendrawtransaction RPC error: {"code":-25,"message":"bad-txns-inputs-missingorspent"}`.

[image].

The transaction is invalid due to incorrectly specifying the output list position of the UTXO used in the inputs.

Comment: I'm missing something... then why that transaction is in my mempool? I thought that bitcoin nodes discards incorrect transactions. I have not generated it... I'm puzzled.

Comment: What node software are you using?

Comment: By the way there is a mistake in the json I've sent you. I'm sorry. It was taken from my program instead from bitcoin-rpc. It seems that not all vouts index are 0. but my program are not taking them correctly (I bet I have fogotten a setter somewhere) . anyway something is wrong because the hex value I've sent you is correct.

Comment: I'm using bitcoin core 0.20.1 on ubuntu

Comment: I'm getting nervous. F**k me if I've discovered a consensus bug. O_o

Comment: I have two nodes: one in a raspberry pi and other in my pc. I use Raspberry pi for having the best mempool I can (always online). The other pc is used for development and it's shutdown when needed. When I need a "good" mempool in my pc I use a tool to query all tx in a mempool and send them to the other node. See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/63675/synchronize-mempool-between-3-nodes The node that has accepted that tx is the development one. not the pi4. both are 0.20.1 versions. Now I'm sending that transaction from the pc to the pi4. but I get an error code

Comment: My mistake, you are correct, the vouts in the txhex are correct.

Comment: I found this though: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/3791f433180a6807695da26e1c0b7f7328a15cbe727ad4ce7c7acbc18b77c5a0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115795/discussion-between-murch-and-jramos).